# Can AS3 set the Accept Header for Flash Player (not AIR)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

"Accept" is not listed in the forbidden headers in the documentation here:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html

but cant seem to set it in a GET request. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to specify the "accept" header, but only on a POST request with one or more variables.

The documentation comments mention this:

> For browser-based Flash/AS3 applications, the only way to successfully set 
>   or modify request headers on a URLRequest object is to set its method to 
>   POST as well as send at least one variable of data along with the request 
>   (i.e. with URLVariables). Otherwise the headers will silently remain 
>   unchanged.

Comment: ugh...well that explains the other bizzareness, but unfortunately I need to set the Accept Header on a GET request (just updated the question to add that)

Comment: Then, unfortunately, the answer is "no." Flash is the only platform specifically designed to infuriate, unfortunately.